# Is there a way how to determine count of equal char in cell of array in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

What are the best way's how can you determine count of equal **characters** in **cell of array** in **c++** ?

We have two-dimensional array with two columns: 
abcda1s aba2cccc

and I need to get the highest number of equal characters from both of these cells, obviously here it,s character 'c' and its used five times .

So my problem here is to determine the character which is used the most, and the number of times it is used.

Comment: -1: unclear, undetailed question. How about showing some code or an example desired input/output?

Comment: What's a cell? Will std::cout or std::count_if work? Or do you mean make a histogram?

Comment: If the c's were not there, what would be the highest count? Does contiguity matter? Can you use a destructive algorithm (i.e. can you sort the elements or does the original location matter after the count)? What do you mean by a 1 dimensional array but 2 columns each of which contain 7/8 chars? Is that not at the very least 2D? These details are important, the problem is not well defined and thus cannot be answered

Comment: a's - four of them. No contiguity doesn't matter. I'm beginner at programming. No, original location doesn't matter. Yeah that's mistake on my part, and  David you'ŗe right it's two-dimensional.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `HashMap<char, unsigned int> myMap` and go one time through your two dimensional array and do for every char:

```
myMap['C'] += 1;
```

where 'C' is your current char.

After that you go through your map and search for the char with the highest int.

If you don't know HashMap's, look [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map).

Comment: No real need for a hash, an array(/vector) would do better and be more straight forward

Comment: No wouldn't it, because you always have to search if a specific element is already in the list, so runtime would be much bigger. Even if the element is in the list, you have to search for it to avoid duplicates which takes O(n) in every run.